# How do I automatically sync a file in cluster?

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization

I have a website growing very fast, and now I put it in several web servers.
Now the problem is how do I sync files between them; I use SVN to manage my source code, I could only commit the source code one by one now, is there a solution to commit the source code to one server and automatically sync to other servers?

Comment: Why do you have TWO SVN servers? Shouldn't one be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can have read-only mirrors, but (as I understand it) you have to have only a single read/write master repository.  It involves setting up some hook scripts that are run when commits are made.  See this reference:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication

Note that if your master (read/write) node goes down, you can convert one of the (read-only) mirror nodes to be the master.

If you truly need multiple read/write mirrors, you'll probably have to look outside of subversion's provided capabilities. The big problem will be if the synchronization process can't keep up with check-ins happening at different mirrors, either due to simultaneous check-ins or intermittent network connectivity.  Could get to be a real headache.  To avoid such headaches, you might want to consider a distributed version control system, such as hg or git.

Comment: Thx a lot,I'm chinese,my english is not very good.What I mean is commit the source code to one svn server,and use post-commit hook to sync the file to other servers,but i didn't know how should the script write

Comment: That makes sense.  So will read-only server mirrors work for you?  Did you see the example scripts provided in the reference I cited?  They are a few pages down.  I have used the setup described in that document and it worked for me.